# Query condition for select leap years in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, leap-year

I have a year column in one of my table and i need to find those years which are **leap year** in MySQL. The table name is 'Movie' and I have a particular year and title column in it. How to find the movies in leap year in SQL query?

I wrote the above query but got the year 'I 2009' in my answer.

```
SELECT year, title from Movie where year%4=0 AND (year%100!=0 OR year%400=0)
```

The head of the data is like this:

```
    title                       Year
0   The Avengers                2012
1   Captain America: Civil War  2016
2   Lion                        2016
3   Slumdog Millionaire         2008
4   2012                      I 2009
```

Comment: changed it, still getting 'I 2011' and 'I 2009' in the result along with those leap years. How to discard them?

Comment: Add sample CREATE TABLE / INSERT INTO scripts (or create a fiddle) which allows to see the described issue.

Comment: @Akina AFAIK `year` is not reserved.

Comment: `'I 2009'` is cated to `0`.

Comment: *The head of the data is like this:* This is table-formatted text, not SQL script. It does not allow even to define where is the value and where is formatting space.

Comment: @Akina, because I am running SQL Script in Jupyter notebook. I can share the .db file with you if you want.

Comment: Yes, even on a smartphone - what's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT @year,
       DAY(CONCAT(@year, '-03-01') - INTERVAL 1 DAY) = 29 AS is_leap;
```

or

```
SELECT @year,
       !MOD(@year, 4) - !MOD(@year, 100) + !MOD(@year, 400) AS is_leap;
```

---

Accordingly

```
SELECT year, title 
FROM Movie 
WHERE DAY(CONCAT(year, '-03-01') - INTERVAL 1 DAY) = 29
```

or

```
SELECT year, title 
FROM Movie 
WHERE !MOD(year, 4) - !MOD(year, 100) + !MOD(year, 400)
```

Comment: Interesting.. How about `day(last_day(concat(@year, '-02-01')))`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel The only difference between leap and non-leap year is the presence/absence `Feb, 29`. So you may substract 1 day from `Mar, 1`, or add 1 day to `Feb, 28`, and check the day of the resulted date.

Comment: changed it, still getting 'I 2011' and 'I 2009' in the result along with those leap years. How to discard them?

Comment: @ShauryaSheth I cannot reproduce your problem, sample data needed - see comment to the question. I don't understand where leading `'I '` symbols are taken from...

Comment: title                                         Year                  
0 The Avengers                         2012
1 Captain America: Civil War 2016
2 Lion                                         2016
3 Slumdog Millionaire                 2008
4 2012                               I 2009

Comment: Not as a comment. Edit question text please. And add SQL scripts, not data only.

Comment: @Akina I guess you didn't get what I'm after. See [LAST_DAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel This is one more solution variant.

Answer (score 0):

For all years when there are movies, this suffices:

```
where year % 4 = 0
```

The more exact expression is:

```
where (year % 4 = 0 and year % 100 <> 0) or
      (year % 400 = 0)
```

`IN` is not appropriate for this condition.

Comment: How to remove those values. there is some wrong data entry in the table

Comment: (1) Why are years being stored as strings?  (2) Why does the year have a non-year value?  You should fix the data, not the query.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data type of the year column a character type?
By using ceil and cast functions, it checks whether it is in numerical format.

```
SELECT year, title from Movie where year%4=0 AND (year%100!=0 OR year%400=0) AND year=cast(ceil(year) as char);
```

> 4   2012                      I 2009

It may be an application problem.
If the data of "2012" that matched the conditions of the leap year is in the year column, and the data of the title column is NULL, so the title column is misaligned and the year column output like it.
If above, I think that 'I ' is incorrect data output by referring to the area outside the range.

Answer (score 0):

Need to format the Year column and then check the Leap Year condition.

```
WHERE (
(
   CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(year),-4) AS INTEGER)%4=0 
   AND 
   CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(year),-4) AS INTEGER)%100!=0
)

OR 
(
 CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(year),-4) AS INTEGER)%100=0 
 AND 
 CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(year),-4) AS INTEGER)%400=0)
)
```